# How to create a network of neighbors?

Tags: gis, netlogo

Hi I am new to netlogo with no programming background, 
I am trying to create a network of "neighbours" , using GIS extension , 
so far I'm using `in-radius` function but i am not sure if it's the one that is suitable. 
since i don't understand the unit of `radius` in Netlogo

here's the code :

```
to setup
  clear-drawing
  clear-all
  reset-ticks

  ; zoom to study area
  resize-world 00 45 0 20
  set-patch-size 20

  ; upload city boundries
  set mosul-data gis:load-dataset"data/MosulBoundries.shp"
  gis:set-world-envelope gis:envelope-of mosul-data
  gis:apply-coverage mosul-data "Q_NAME_E" neighbor


to Neighbour-network
  ;; set 7 neighbour agents inside the city  
  ask turtles [ 
    let target other turtles in-radius 1 
    if any? target
    [ask one-of target [create-link-with myself]]
  ]
  print count links
```

I want for each neighberhood `neighbor` each agent is linked to the 7 nearst neighbors.
my guess is that in the line `if any? target` something has to change , but all my attempts are useless so far.

Thank in advance

Comment: What are your turtles? You haven't included any code to create turtles and I can't work out how the GIS is relevant to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unclear how GIS relates to this question and you haven't provided the code for creating the agents so I can't give a complete answer. NetLogo has a coordinate system, automatically built in. Each agent has a position on that coordinate system and each patch occupies the space 1 unit by 1 unit square (centred on integer coordinates). The `in-radius` and `distance` primitives are in the distance units.

However, if all you want to do is connect to the 7 nearest turtles, you don't need any of that because NetLogo can simply find those turtles directly by finding those with the minimum distance to the asking turtle. This uses `min-n-of` to find the given number of turtles with the relevant minimum, and `distance [myself]` for the thing to minimise. The whole thing, including creating the links with the generated turtleset, can be done in a single line of code.

Here is a complete model to show you what it looks like:

```
to testme
  clear-all
  create-turtles 100 [setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
  ask n-of 5 turtles
  [ create-links-with min-n-of 7 other turtles [distance myself]
  ]
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Sarah:

1) This helped me understand the use of 'in-radius' in NetLogo (or the unit of radius): When you use 'in-radius 1' in a patch-context, 5 patches will be selected (patch where the asking turtle is located and four neighbors, *not all 8 neighboring patches*).

[image]

2) Consider using 'min-one-of target [ distance myself ]' instead of 'one-of target'.

min-one-of: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/min-one-of.html

distance myself: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/distance.html

```
to Neighbour-network
; set 7 neighbour agents inside the city
ask turtles [
    let target other turtles in-radius 1
    let counter 0
    while [ count target > 0 and counter < 8 ]
    [ ask min-one-of target [ distance myself ] [
        create-link-with myself
        set counter counter + 1
      ]
    ]
    show my-links
  ]
```

3) Consider exploring Nw extension: https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/nw.html

Comment: This answer is not correct. The primitive `in-radius` will select any agents within a distance of 1 unit regardless of the patch where they are located. And the `nw` is not relevant at all. If `nw` is relevant somehow, you should give code that shows how, not just link to the documentation, especially as you haven't even identified the relevant primitives.

Comment: Why so aggressive, JenB?

Comment: It is not aggressive to identify errors in the answer, otherwise people will get more confused than they were before. The edits have improved the answer, though the `nw` extension is still irrelevant and your demonstration of `in-radius` with patches doesn't explain why it returns the 4 patches (because it is measuring centre to centre)

Comment: Right! And I had also suggested the use of 'min-one-of' and 'distance myself' which now you include in your answer. Thanks, JenB!